# How to set Android Phone to be a target mode for NFC Reader?

Tags: android, nfc, sony

I would like to set my Android phone(Sony Xperia S) to be a target mode for NFC Reader (ACR122U) for make the Reader recognize my phone.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sony Xperia S cannot be detected ACR122U NFC Reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964625/sony-xperia-s-cannot-be-detected-acr122u-nfc-reader)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start here: http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/07/android-host-card-emulation-with-acr122/

If you can set the NFC reader (ACR122U) as initiator in P2P mode, the Android phone will usually be the target. However, if you want to use Android beam, the NFC reader has to support the SNEP protocol using LLCP.